# What version of Windows 10 will I get?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10-upgrade

My friend has Windows 7 Home Premium. Which version of Windows 10 will it be eligible to upgrade to?

I have a volume license for Windows 7 Professional, should I update computers with Windows 7 Home to Windows 7 Pro before doing the upgrade to Windows 10?

Or will all the updating computers get the same "free version" of Windows 10?

I have googled, but nothing I've read is specifically identifying the version of Windows 10 I will get when I update.

Does anyone here know more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows 7 Home Premium will get Windows 10 Home.
Windows 7 Professional will get Windows 10 Pro.

Here is the upgrade matrix:
[image: Here is the upgrade matrix:]
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications

Yes, you should update your Windows 7 Home Premium to Windows 7 Professional if you wish to get Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: can you link to where that picture came from?

Comment: I just googled Windows 10 Upgrade Matrix or Upgrade Paths or something along those lines. There are a bunch of articles with the information. Here is the one I used: http://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-has-announced-the-upgrade-matrix-for-windows-10

Comment: I found the official Microsoft page/link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications Scroll down to Upgrade Editions.